# HTML5 Pattern for writing name

Tags: html

Pattern for writing name in HTML5

I wrote below pattern but it's not working for me.

**[A-Za-z]+\s?**

I want a pattern that accept the name with below functionalities

1. Start with a letter.
2. Can contain only first name.
3. Can contain multiple names (first middle last).
4. Should contain only one space among names if multiple.
5. Should not contain space at the end and last of input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For 1, 2 and 5: use the ^(start of line) and $(end of line) pattern**

`^[A-Za-z]+$` matches a set of characters with no space(first name in this case)

**For 3 and 4: use groups and repitition**

`(\s[A-Za-z]+)` matches a single space followed by any number of characters(space followed by middle / last names) -- *Group*.

Since there could be 0 to 2 such occurences(Only First, First & Last(?), First, Middle and Last), this changes to `(\s[A-Za-z]+){0,2}` -- *Repitition*

Combining these will give the expression you need: `^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+){0,2}$`